# Updating multiple legends in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

In layout view I have many pages with different parts of the main map. For each of these I have a legend.

Is it possible to designate all of them the same kind, and when I update one I update all?

Comment: What kind of updates do you want to make? You can, for example, link the legend to the contents in your map canvas. That would change the legend if the content is changed and makes sure only the content is displayed in the legend.

Comment: I have a "master" layout. There are many maps all showing the same layers, but different locations. And I use this layout to show different analysis' but everytime I make a new one, I have to delete all legends but one, update that one, and copy it to the other pages.